# Difference between "cladding" and "traces" in PCBs?

Tags: pcb, pcb-design, pcb-layers

I am kind of confused about, the difference between copper traces and copper cladding in PCBs.

Are they the same thing?

Is it necessary for a PCB to have them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Cladding* is the copper layer applied to the surface of a board substrate: it's the starting material. This layer is selectively etched away to form traces in the finished PCB.

Answer (score 0):

Same thing. Copper clad means the fiberglass PCB substrate is clad in copper foil which is etched away to make traces.

I guess it's not necessary for a PCB to have copper cladding. Instead of a PCB with copper traces on a fiberglass substrate, you would a bare fiberglass substrate with components mounted on it with the electrical connections being made by something like wire wrap or point-to-point wires.

Comment: aka "tagboard" or "tag strip", pre-dating PCBs, from the vacuum tube era. https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/475056/why-did-axial-capacitors-fall-out-of-use-in-the-industry/475059#475059